# The use of sizeof in malloc

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, malloc, sizeof

I am trying to wrap the creation of a matrix into a function, but I am having problems trying to understand the following code snippet extracted from a book:

```
  // An error checked malloc() wrapper function
  void *ec_malloc(unsigned int size) {
     void *ptr;
     ptr = malloc(size);
     if(ptr == NULL)
        fatal("in ec_malloc() on memory allocation");
     return ptr;
  }
```

I've already check this question:

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/)

And now I now it is not necessary to cast the result. But what I don't understand is the use of `malloc(size)` without a `sizeof` operator. For example, to create a matrix, lets say `int **matrix` I've also created this function:

```
  // An error checked malloc() wrapper function
  void **double_ec_malloc(unsigned int size) {
     void **ptr;
     ptr = malloc(size);
     if(ptr == NULL)
        fatal("in ec_malloc() on memory allocation");
     return ptr;
  }
```

And then I do:

```
  int **matrixA = double_ec_malloc(size);

  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    matrixA[i] = ec_malloc(size);
```

The `man` of `malloc` says:

> The malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.

Let `size` be `4`, then in `ptr = malloc(size)` I am allocating 4 bytes, but if matrix is of type `int`. Wouldn't I need `sizeof int * 4`? Because right now I think I am not allocating enough memory for an integer matrix.

Comment: this doesn't make sense. why would you return `void **` from a `malloc()` wrapper? And what's wrong with `sizeof`? If you **know** that you **have to** use it for correctness, then why are you not using it?

Comment: That book is full of it. `malloc()`, at least nowadays, expects a `size_t` argument, not an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ec_malloc()` doesn't take a datatype argument, it assumes you will do `sizeof(datatype) * size` yourself. Thus the argument `unsigned int size` should be in bytes.

Notice how that it is exactly how `malloc()` itself behaves.

Comment: Dude, Thank you very much!, It's been quite a long time since I do not program in C that I was having troubles understanding pointers again.  Your answer made me realizes that I was using `ec_malloc` wrong. I only need to call it this way `ec_malloc(sizeof(int) * tam)`. I am feeling now such an idiot for asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

The `malloc` function (and your `ec_malloc`) both allocate a linear region of bytes that is `size` bytes long.

`sizeof` simply returns an `int` and it isn't related to `malloc` in any way (other than it is frequently used with `malloc`).

A 32-bit integer is 4 bytes long.  `sizeof(int)` returns 4.  If you want space for 4 `int`s, you would say `malloc( sizeof(int) * 4 )`.